# What is the plug-in MLE of this distribution?

Tags: maximum-likelihood

The question is as follows. Suppose that $(X_1, X_2, X_3) \sim Multinomial(n, \theta_1, \theta_2, \theta_3)$, where
$$ \Omega = \{(\theta_1, \theta_2, \theta_3) : 0 \leq \theta_i \leq 1, \theta_1+\theta_2+\theta_3 = 1\}$$
and we observe $(X_1, X_2, X_3) = (x_1, x_2, x_3)$.

I determined the MLE to be $\theta = (x_1/n, x_2/n, x_3/n)$ using constrained optimization, but it then asks what the plug-in MLE of $\theta_1 + \theta_2^2 - \theta_3^2$ is. Do I just plug in the corresponding values? What does the plug-in MLE even mean?

Answer (score 1):

If a statistic is a function of the parameters of a parametric distribution, then the "plug in MLE estimate" is just putting the maximum likelihood estimates into the function directly. It *is* as easy as it sounds. A different approach would be conceptualizing a different probabilty model, a change of variable, or other to give a different estimator with different properties.

Comment: A "statistic" is some function of the data but here you talk about a parameter (being some function of other parameters) so the above statement is not entirely correct.

Comment: @JarleTufto yes thanks, I think I need some more general language for that kind of estimation problem.